# How to start installation after downloading apk in mono

Tags: c#, android, mono, installation, apk

I've been struggling to get my application to update from my private server I cannot get the broadcast receiver to work nor a plain installation script PLEASE I'm going insane Any Help would be deeply appreciated.

my script

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://www.Site.cc/Folder/app.apk");

            // If required by the server, set the credentials.
            //request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
            //request.IfModifiedSince = DateTime.Parse("01-01-1990");
            try
            {
                using (WebResponse response = request.GetResponse())
                {

                    //DateTime dt = System.IO.File.GetCreationTime(FilePath);        //.GetLastWriteTime(FilePath);
                   // DateTime appDate = DateTime.Parse(response.Headers["Last-Modified"].ToString());

                    try
                    {
                        ad = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).Create();
                        ad.SetTitle("INFO");

                        ad.SetMessage("Get New version");
                        ad.SetButton("NOW", delegate
                        {


                            System.IO.File.Delete("/filepath/app.apk");
                            string url = "http://www.Site.cc/Folder/App.apk";
                            DownloadManager.Request Request = new DownloadManager.Request(Android.Net.Uri.Parse(url));
                            Request.SetDescription("Inspections Application");
                            Request.SetTitle("Download Inspections");
                            // in order for this if to run, you must use the android 3.2 to compile your app
                            if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= BuildVersionCodes.HoneycombMr1)
                            {
                                Request.AllowScanningByMediaScanner();
                                Request.SetNotificationVisibility(DownloadVisibility.VisibleNotifyCompleted);
                                Request.SetMimeType("application/vnd.android.package-archive");
                                Request.SetVisibleInDownloadsUi(true);

                            }
                            Request.SetDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Android.OS.Environment.DirectoryDownloads, "Inspections.Inspections-Signed.apk");

                            // get download service and enqueue file
                            DownloadManager manager = (DownloadManager)GetSystemService(Context.DownloadService);
                            manager.Enqueue(Request);


                        });
                        ad.SetButton2("LATER", delegate
                        {
                            return;
                        });
                        //ad.SetButton("Continue",new IDialogInterfaceOnClickListener listner);
                        ad.SetCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
                        ad.Show();


                    }
                    catch (System.Exception ex)
                    {
                        ad = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).Create();
                        ad.SetTitle("INFO");
                        ad.SetMessage(ex.Message);
                        ad.SetCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
                        ad.Show();
                    }
                   /* 
                        cL.DownloadFile("http://www.site.cc/folder/app.apk", Path);
                        Intent promptInstall = new Intent(Intent.ActionView).SetData(Android.Net.Uri.Parse("/sdcard/Download/Inspections.Inspections-Signed.apk")).SetType("application/vnd.android.package-archive");
                        StartActivity(promptInstall); 
                    */
                    //string lastModified = DateTime.Parse(response.Headers["Last-Modified"].ToString()).ToString();
                }
            }
            catch (WebException wex)
            {

            }
```

if I could just find a way to start the installation wiz for the app when its finished downloading

I know it must ask for permissions

Device log:

```
06-28 07:17:55.843 I/MonoDroid(  860): UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: Android.Content.ActivityNotFoundException: Exception of type 'Android.Content.ActivityNotFoundException' was thrown.
06-28 07:17:55.843 I/MonoDroid(  860): at Android.Runtime.JNIEnv.CallNonvirtualVoidMethod (intptr,intptr,intptr,Android.Runtime.JValue[]) [0x00024] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/monodroid-mac-monodroid-4.2.7-branch/0e9eea34/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/src/Runtime/JNIEnv.g.cs:616
06-28 07:17:55.843 I/MonoDroid(  860): at Android.Content.ContextWrapper.StartActivity (Android.Content.Intent) [0x0006b] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/monodroid-mac-monodroid-4.2.7-branch/0e9eea34/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/platforms/android-12/src/generated/Android.Content.ContextWrapper.cs:2318
06-28 07:17:55.843 I/MonoDroid(  860): at Inspections.Activity1.<checkdate>b__8 (object,Android.Content.DialogClickEventArgs) [0x00031] in f:\aa\c#\android\Inspections\Activity1.cs:519
06-28 07:17:55.843 I/MonoDroid(  860): at Android.Content.IDialogInterfaceOnClickListenerInvoker.n_OnClick_Landroid_content_DialogInterface_I (intptr,intptr,intptr,int) [0x00010] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/monodroid-mac-monodroid-4.2.7-branch/0e9eea34/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/platforms/android-12/src/generated/Android.Content.IDialogInterface.cs:172
06-28 07:17:55.843 I/MonoDroid(  860): at (wrapper dynamic-method) object.0ae0dbc0-1a91-4175-9a2f-597c804b25ec (intptr,intptr,intptr,int) <IL 0x00018, 0x0003b>
06-28 07:17:55.843 I/MonoDroid(  860): 
06-28 07:17:55.843 I/MonoDroid(  860):   --- End of managed exception stack trace ---
06-28 07:17:55.843 I/MonoDroid(  860): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW typ=application/vnd.android.package-archive flg=0x10000000 }
06-28 07:17:55.843 I/MonoDroid(  860):  at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1580)
06-28 07:17:55.843 I/MonoDroid(  860):  at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1431)
06-28 07:17:55.843 I/MonoDroid(  860):  at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3390)
06-28 07:17:55.843 I/MonoDroid(  860):  at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3351)
06-28 07:17:55.843 I/MonoDroid(  860):  at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3561)
06-28 07:17:55.843 I/MonoDroid(  860):  at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3529)
06-28 07:17:55.843 I/MonoDroid(  860):  at mono.android.content.DialogInterface_OnClickListenerImplementor.n_onClick(Native Method)
06-28 07:17:55.843 I/MonoDroid(  860):  at mono.android.content.DialogInterface_OnClickListenerImplementor.onClick(DialogInterface_OnClickListenerImplementor.java:29)
06-28 07:17:55.843 I/MonoDroid(  860):  at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:167)
06-28 07:17:55.843 I/MonoDroid(  860):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-28 07:17:55.843 I/MonoDroid(  860):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-28 07:17:55.843 I/MonoDroid(  860):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4867)
06-28 07:17:55.843 I/MonoDroid(  860):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-28 07:17:55.843 I/MonoDroid(  860):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-28 07:17:55.843 I/MonoDroid(  860):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1007)
06-28 07:17:55.843 I/MonoDroid(  860):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:774)
06-28 07:17:55.843 I/MonoDroid(  860):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-28 07:17:55.873 W/dalvikvm(  860): JNI WARNING: JNI method called with exception pending
06-28 07:17:55.873 W/dalvikvm(  860):              in Lmono/android/content/DialogInterface_OnClickListenerImplementor;.n_onClick:(Landroid/content/DialogInterface;I)V (CallObjectMethod)
06-28 07:17:55.873 W/dalvikvm(  860): Pending exception is:
06-28 07:17:55.873 I/dalvikvm(  860): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW typ=application/vnd.android.package-archive flg=0x10000000 }
06-28 07:17:55.873 I/dalvikvm(  860):   (raw stack trace not found)
06-28 07:17:55.873 I/dalvikvm(  860): "main" prio=5 tid=1 NATIVE
06-28 07:17:55.873 I/dalvikvm(  860):   | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x4127a508 self=0x41269450
06-28 07:17:55.873 I/dalvikvm(  860):   | sysTid=860 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=[no-cpu-subsys] handle=1074679600
06-28 07:17:55.873 I/dalvikvm(  860):   | schedstat=( 3794555681 1447662333 6173 ) utm=289 stm=90 core=0
06-28 07:17:55.883 I/dalvikvm(  860):   #00  pc 00001260  /system/lib/libcorkscrew.so (unwind_backtrace_thread+27)
06-28 07:17:55.883 I/dalvikvm(  860):   #01  pc 0005f97c  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmDumpNativeStack(DebugOutputTarget const*, int)+35)
06-28 07:17:55.883 I/dalvikvm(  860):   #02  pc 00053824  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmDumpThreadEx(DebugOutputTarget const*, Thread*, bool)+303)
06-28 07:17:55.883 I/dalvikvm(  860):   #03  pc 000538be  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmDumpThread(Thread*, bool)+25)
06-28 07:17:55.883 I/dalvikvm(  860):   #04  pc 00038e7a  /system/lib/libdvm.so
06-28 07:17:55.883 I/dalvikvm(  860):   #05  pc 00040fd8  /system/lib/libdvm.so
06-28 07:17:55.883 I/dalvikvm(  860):   at mono.android.content.DialogInterface_OnClickListenerImplementor.n_onClick(Native Method)
06-28 07:17:55.883 I/dalvikvm(  860):   at mono.android.content.DialogInterface_OnClickListenerImplementor.onClick(DialogInterface_OnClickListenerImplementor.java:29)
06-28 07:17:55.883 I/dalvikvm(  860):   at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:167)
06-28 07:17:55.883 I/dalvikvm(  860):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-28 07:17:55.883 I/dalvikvm(  860):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-28 07:17:55.893 I/dalvikvm(  860):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4867)
06-28 07:17:55.893 I/dalvikvm(  860):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-28 07:17:55.893 I/dalvikvm(  860):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-28 07:17:55.893 I/dalvikvm(  860):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1007)
06-28 07:17:55.893 I/dalvikvm(  860):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:774)
06-28 07:17:55.893 I/dalvikvm(  860):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-28 07:17:55.893 I/dalvikvm(  860): 
06-28 07:17:55.893 E/dalvikvm(  860): VM aborting
06-28 07:17:55.893 I/mono    (  860): Stacktrace:
06-28 07:17:55.893 I/mono    (  860): 
06-28 07:17:55.893 I/mono    (  860):   at Android.Runtime.JNIEnv.CallObjectMethod (intptr,intptr) [0x00000] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/monodroid-mac-monodroid-4.2.7-branch/0e9eea34/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/src/Runtime/JNIEnv.g.cs:129
06-28 07:17:55.893 I/mono    (  860):   at Java.Lang.Throwable.get_Message () [0x0003e] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/monodroid-mac-monodroid-4.2.7-branch/0e9eea34/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/platforms/android-12/src/generated/Java.Lang.Throwable.cs:175
06-28 07:17:55.893 I/mono    (  860):   at (wrapper runtime-invoke) <Module>.runtime_invoke_object__this__ (object,intptr,intptr,intptr) <IL 0x00050, 0xffffffff>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I have found the Solution

```
System.IO.File.Delete("/sdcard/download/App_Name.apk"); //Delete previous version
```

.

```
cL.DownloadFile("http://www.Site.cc/Folder/App_Name.apk", "/sdcard/download/App_Name.apk");// Download new app via HttpWebRequest
```

new working code

```
Intent promptInstall = new Intent(Intent.ActionView).SetDataAndType(Android.Net.Uri.FromFile(new Java.IO.File(Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory + "/download/" + "App_Name.apk")), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
promptInstall.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask);
StartActivity(promptInstall);
```

Old not working code

```
Intent promptInstall = new Intent(Intent.ActionView).SetData(Android.Net.Uri.Parse("/sdcard/Download/App_Name.apk")).SetType("application/vnd.android.package-archive");
promptInstall.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask);
StartActivity(promptInstall);
```

newbie problem but its solved

Answer (score 0):

You need to start an activity with Intent parameters like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(apkUri, "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
```

`apkUri` is a URI that points to your APK file.

Comment: I have tried

Intent promptInstall = new Intent(Intent.ActionView).SetData(Android.Net.Uri.Parse("/sdcard/Download/Inspections.Inspections-Signed.apk")).SetType("application/vnd.android.package-archive");
                        StartActivity(promptInstall);

and get ActivityNotFoundException

Comment: Can you look in the logcat (don't filter the logcat, otherwise you might miss it) when this happens and see what the `Intent` looks like that it is trying to resolve? You should see a message that it cannot resolve the `Intent` and it should tell you what the `Intent` looks like. Please post that.

Comment: Hi David 

Thank you for the Response Please see my edit where Device Log is posted

Comment: If you look at the error: `android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW typ=application/vnd.android.package-archive flg=0x10000000 }` you can see that the ACTION and TYPE are correctly set, but the DATA (ie: URI) seems to be empty. It looks like your code `Android.Net.Uri.Parse("/sdcard/Download/Inspec‌​tions.Inspections-Signed.apk")` is returning `null` instead of the correct URI. Maybe you can check that (add logging or whatever). I'm not familiar with mono so I can't be more help, sorry.

Comment: thank you David just found the solution I also noted the Uri was null so I changed it and its working 200% Thank you so much for your time All the best